# Maven Dependency Plugin command line option to EXCLUDE optional dependencies when downloading dependencies to local directory

Tags: java, maven

I figured that one can easily download all dependencies including transitive ones for a given artifact using the maven dependency plugin command line. For example the below two commands can be used to download & copy all dependencies for artifact [atmosphere-runtime](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.atmosphere/atmosphere-runtime/2.3.3), including only the compile & provided dependencies and excluding test ones,

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:get -DgroupId=org.atmosphere -DartifactId=atmosphere-runtime -Dversion=2.3.3 -Dtype=pom

mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy-dependencies -f <path-to-local-repo>\org\atmosphere\atmosphere-runtime\2.3.3\atmosphere-runtime-2.3.3.pom -DoutputDirectory=<path-to-target-dir> -DincludeScope=compile
```

But the problem with the above is that it includes dependencies which are tagged as optional. Continuing with the example above, the artifact "grizzly-framework-http" which is tagged as an optional dependency for "atmosphere-runtime" gets downloaded/copied along with all its transitive dependencies.

Is there a way to filter out or exclude such dependencies which are tagged as "(optional)" when downloading dependencies?

Comment: I reported this feature request https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-661

Answer (score 1):

Why are you downloading your dependencies manually?
Use a POM file to describe your project. You can add dependency exclusions and the dependencies will be downloaded as you require and will be available from your local repository.

Here are some helpful references:
http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Exclusions

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reference. Well, we don't use maven in our environment. My requirement is just to find & download all dependencies (including transitive) for specific libraries  that i wish to upgrade. I found maven's dependency plugin very useful to do this (I know there are other ways like using Apache ivy, etc.). Nevertheless, i still don't quite understand how i can solve the problem i mentioned earlier.

Comment: create POM file, define dummy arifact etc along with required dependencies. Run CMD from there `mvn compile` - nothing will be build, but dependencies will get downloaded. to your local mvn repo.

Comment: Thanks Antoniossss. I have no problems downloading dependencies. The problem is how to exclude ones that are marked "optional".
 
If you look at the below maven repo link for my artifact "atmosphere-runtime",
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.atmosphere/atmosphere-runtime/2.3.3

You will see that some of its dependencies are tagged optional,
com.sun.grizzly » grizzly-framework-http (optional) 1.0.31 1.0.51
com.sun.grizzly » grizzly-websockets (optional) 1.9.57 2.3.22
org.apache.geronimo.specs » geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec (optional) 1.0 ✔
Now the problem is how do i filter out the above.